# ceph snapshots are not running

Tags: linux, snapshot, ceph

Our ceph cluster (quincy 17.2.7) runs in a docker container. The snapshot schedule was created as:

```
ceph fs snap-schedule add / 1h 2023-12-13T09:00:00 nerfcomputing2024
```

and retention:

```
ceph fs snap-schedule retention add / n 30 nerfcomputing2024
```

The inputs are correct as shown in the status below, however, snapshot never started as seen in `"first": null, "last": null`
Note that as shown below,  `snap_schedule is on`

Also note that [ceph docs](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/dev/cephfs-snapshots/#creating-a-snapshot) says to do `ceph fs set <fs_name> allow_new_snaps true`, which I did it. However, when I grep for `snaps`, the closest match is `allow_snaps` I assume this is the same than `allow_new_snaps`. I finally would like to point out that the `.snap` folders in the volume are there.

```
root@nerffs14:/# sudo ceph fs snap-schedule status
{"fs": "nerfcomputing2024", "subvol": null, "path": "/", "rel_path": "/", "schedule": "1h", "retention": {"n": 30}, "start": "2023-12-13T09:00:00", "created": "2023-12-13T08:53:16", "first": null, "last": null, "last_pruned": null, "created_count": 0, "pruned_count": 0, "active": true}
root@nerffs14:/# sudo ceph fs get nerfcomputing2024 | grep snaps
flags   12 joinable allow_snaps allow_multimds_snaps
root@nerffs14:/# sudo ceph mgr module ls | grep snap_schedule
snap_schedule         on            
root@nerffs14:/# ceph --version
ceph version 17.2.7 (b12291d110049b2f35e32e0de30d70e9a4c060d2) quincy (stable)
root@nerffs14:/#
```

Any idea why the snapshots are not running?

Comment: Have you tried a mgr failover (`ceph mgr fail`)? There are a few threads https://lists.ceph.io/hyperkitty/list/ceph-users@ceph.io/message/5QAHYUKEGP2Y7HPKBH3IXL6NNOPK3FNT/, https://lists.ceph.io/hyperkitty/list/ceph-users@ceph.io/message/HXGCMEIJG4GU6CZW6WVUXKXTVRZIQUNK/ describing a similar problem but without a solution yet. Did it ever work for you or did it just stop working?

Comment: @eblock, that never worked for me. However, now is working after doing `ceph fs snap-schedule activate`. So, it seems that the output of `ceph fs snap-schedule status` -> `"active": true}` does not really mean the snap is active

Answer (score 0):

Now is working after doing `ceph fs snap-schedule activate`. So, it seems that the output of `ceph fs snap-schedule status` -> `"active": true` does not really mean the snap is active